# How create A-Z Product List Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, product-listing

I need to create a page listing products alphabetically from A to Z and show only the products starting to each letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default sorting to Product Name as place of position

> Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Store Front > Product
>   Listing Sort by

and if you want this to only for particular category then you can change this Category's

> Display Settings tab >  Default Product Listing Sort By to Product Name

check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/pj6nre

Comment: Thank you, but I need to create a listing page for each letter, for example, a page for A and within all the products start with A, and then B and so on for each letter

Comment: its not possible in default and for this you can create drop-down attribute same like brand and then add all options from A to Z and assign this attribute value to all products like name starting with A then assign to A value etc and then on front-end filter products using this attribute